# using cat command to copy a file's contents to all files under a directory (recursively)

Tags: cat

How could we use cat command to copy a file's contents to all the files under a directory (recursively -I mean each and every file)?

Comment: This sounds a bit homeworky, so as a rough pointer, you can use `find ... -exec` to execute commands on all files in a directory.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use `cat` to do that. You'd use something like `find` and `cp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overwrite each file in an entire directory hierarchy with the contents of the file `data`:

```
find . -type f ! -path './data' -exec sh -c 'tee "$@" <data >/dev/null' sh {} +
```

If you want to *append* the contents of `data`, then use `tee -a` in the above.

The `! -path ./data` is to avoid modifying the file that we are reading from.

The child shell will get a bunch of pathnames from `find` and will use `tee` to distribute the contents of `data` to these files.

To use `cat` instead of `tee`:

```
find . -type f ! -path './data' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cat data >"$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Here, to *append* the data, use `>>` in place of `>`.

**Run this in a directory where it's safe to do so. Running it in your home directory will destroy *all* your files.  To recover from that, you will need to restore from a recent backup. Never run commands that you've copied and pasted from the internet, without knowing what they do or may do.**

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)